# Android KitKat new UI picker - not opening

Tags: android, mime-types, tablet, android-4.4-kitkat, picker

I have an Android app running on a **Tablet**.
I want the user to be able to select an image and get it to my app.
I create the following Intent and send it:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
```

Android KitKat introduced a new UI picker. This picker allows to access cloud based accounts such as Google Drive.

I want to be able to get images from there as well.

My problem is that if I set any mime type (`intent.setType`) other than `"*/*"`, the new UI picker does not open. I get the old app chooser.

Please see these images:

While sending mime type "image/*":

[image: With image mime type]

While sending mime type "image/*": (my desired outcome)

[image: With */* mime type]

On a phone there is no problem filtering the files with the mime type, This only happens on Tablets.

Anyone knows how to open the new UI picker with filtered content (only images)?

Thanks!

PB